# Get two images from image which has two images pasted in a single document- Python/C++

Tags: python, c++, image, opencv, computer-vision

I have a document - say the back and front of an ID. Something like this
[The dotted lines are that of a poorly scanned ID, so the borders are not clear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SojM.png)
The objective is to retrieve image 1 and image 2 as two separate images. The scanned documents are black and white.

My questions:
1. Is this feasible?
2. Any ideas/code snippets on how to proceed would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: A proper image would likely elicit a better answer.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Will get back with a proper representative image, cannot upload the actual image for privacy reasons

Comment: Excellent! That will give a clearer indication of the resolution and size, the amount of noise, the separation, the colours - just blur or black out the most sensitive parts but leave as much pattern and border/surround as you can.

Comment: Please ping me back when you have provided an image.

Comment: If you use a Unix-like system, you can try my bash imagemagick scripts, multicrop or multicrop2 at http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/multicrop/index.php and http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/multicrop2/index.php. Examples are shown on these pages and the scripts can be downloaded from them

Comment: @fmw42 Hi Fred, that's pretty nifty and general purpose and deskews rotated documents. You should put it as an answer - help yourself to my sample images.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Apologies, was sick the entire week. Thanks for uploading the images , mine are along similar lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you haven't provided and images... I will provide some samples. I am using **ImageMagick** because you can just do it at the command-line without needing to compile anything, but you can apply exactly the same techniques in OpenCV with Python.

So, here's a sample image.

[image]

Now, the scan may have noise and it may not have pure whites and blacks if not exposed correctly, so as a first step, you could normalise or auto-level the image, threshold it to pure black and white and apply a median filter to remove noise - especially if it is a JPEG.

```
convert scan.jpg -normalize -threshold 90% -median 9x9 -negate result.png
```

[image]

Maybe you want to close the holes now using some morphology:

```
convert scan.jpg -normalize -threshold 90% -median 9x9 -negate -morphology close disk:7 result.png
```

[image]

Now you could do some *"Connected Component Analysis"* to find the blobs:

```
convert scan.jpg -threshold 90% -median 9x9 -negate \
   -morphology close disk:7                         \
   -define connected-components:verbose=1           \
   -connected-components 8 -auto-level result.png
```

**Sample Output**

```
Objects (id: bounding-box centroid area mean-color):
  0: 695x297+0+0 355.4,150.9 107426 srgb(0,0,0)
  2: 276x188+352+54 487.8,148.7 50369 srgb(255,255,255)
  1: 275x194+43+44 185.9,143.3 46695 srgb(255,255,255)
  3: 78x47+56+56 96.4,72.9 1731 srgb(0,0,0)
  4: 18x16+168+183 176.5,190.4 194 srgb(0,0,0)
```

That gives a *"labelled"* image, which we are not actually going to use, but identifies each blob it has found in a successively lighter shade.

[image]

Now look at the textual output above, and you can see there are 5 blobs - one per line. You can check the 4th field which is the area of the blob and the fifth field which is the colour - this will help distinguish between black and white blobs. Let's look at a couple of the blobs and draw them in on the original image:

```
convert scan.jpg -fill "rgba(255,0,0,0.5)" -draw "rectangle 352,54 628,242" result1.png
```

[image]

```
convert scan.jpg -fill "rgba(255,0,0,0.5)" -draw "rectangle 43,44 318,238" result2.png
```

[image]

Now we can chop the individual pages out:

```
convert scan.jpg -crop 276x188+352+54 doc1.png
```

[image]

```
convert scan.jpg -crop 275x194+43+44  doc2.png
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Mark Setchell asked that I show his example with my script, multicrop2, which does something similar to all his commands. See http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/multicrop2/index.php

I noticed that he had a black border around his image. So I need to remove that first with an Imagemagick shave and pipe it to my script, multicrop2.

```
convert vZiPW.jpg -shave 3x3 miff:- | multicrop2 -u 1 -f 1 -m save -d 10000 vZiPW_shaved.png multicrop_results.jpg
```

In the script, I use -u 1 to do a deskew to unrotate the extracted images. I use -f 1 (a fuzz value or tolerance of 1%) to allow for JPG compression changes to the background white color during a floodfill to make a mask. I also save the mask that my script first extracts to locate the two images. Since the images have colors close to white there may be small holes or specks. So my script will fill those holes using a connected components process. Thus it ignores any regions whose areas are smaller than 10000 pixels as indicated by the -d 10000. More importantly, it uses connected components to locate the bounding boxes of the two large regions from the mask and then crops and unrotates the corresponding regions from the input image.

Here is the raw mask after a floodfill operation and before the connected components processing to remove the small specks:

[image]

Here are the two extracted images after the deskew unrotation.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing this!

Comment: Excellent work, Fred! Thank you. Please keep the answers coming so we can all share and learn something.

Answer (score 0):

You can try findContours.

```
findContours (image, contours, hierarchy,                 
              CV_RETR_EXTERNAL,              
              CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE,
              Point(0, 0));
```

Then use drawContours to see if the desired images are selected. 
You can find the bounding box for a contour and need not worry about the bad scan. 
If this doesn't work straight away, try to pre process your image , you could try morphing, thresholding etc.

I hope this helps!

Comment: I assume this is OpenCV. In the future, please identify the code being use.